# Wagtail i18n: only show links to pages that are translated

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm building an i18n website with Wagtail 2.11.3 and followed the documentation at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/i18n.html?highlight=i18n, and four languages. I also use `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to determine the user's preferred language, which "kind of" works (read below).

So I have four languages:

```
WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES = LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', "Deutsch"),
    ('fr', "Français"),
    ('it', "Italiano"),
    ('en', "English"),
]
```

Only parts of the website should be multi-lingual, some pages are only available in one language. I ended up having four page trees, one for each language, and I'm able to create translations.

However, as pointed out, I have some pages that aren't translated at all, but still have a localized version (auto-created when I create a page). So here https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/i18n.html?highlight=i18n#basic-example is an example how the language links can be implemented in the template, but I only want to show the links to pages already translated. Using `django_debug_toolbar` I couldn't find a template variable to check if a page is translated.

How can I accomplish that?

Also related: Using `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` the preferred language is detected, and I'm on `/about_us`. However, if I not explicitly set the language code preceding the url (like `/de/about_us`), the following pages will change back to my browser's language as I navigate at the site. Therefore I'd like something like a redirect to `/de/...` as soon as the Locale middleware detected the language. Is that possible (probably not only Wagtail-related, I'm sorry).

Comment: For the `about_us`url, just wondering if the url in question is inside the i18n url pattern block and the url template tag is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find pages that are in the locale's language tree, but not translated there is a `alias_of` property.

**template.html**

```
{% if self.alias_of %}
   not translated
{% else %}
   translated
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
    if self.alias_of:
        is_translated = self.alias_of.locale is self.locale
```

For more hidden goodies, check the [wagtail-localize](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-localize) repo. I found this in the wagtail_hooks.py